# iphone - Coremotion acceleration always zero!

Tags: iphone

I am trying to grab the device acceleration using CoreMotion. I have this code:

for setting

```
if (motionManager == nil) 
        motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = framesPorKeyframes / 60.0; //60 Hz
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval =  framesPorKeyframes / 60.0; //60 Hz

[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
referenceAttitude = nil;
```

for reading

```
vec3f_t translation = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
CMRotationMatrix rotation;
CMAcceleration userAcceleration;


CMDeviceMotion *deviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion;      
attitude = deviceMotion.attitude;

rotation = attitude.rotationMatrix;

userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration;
[userAccelerationLpf addAcceleration:userAcceleration withTimestamp:deviceMotion.timestamp];

// The user acceleration we want to use is the one computed by userAccelerationLpf
userAcceleration.x = userAccelerationLpf.x;
userAcceleration.y = userAccelerationLpf.y;
userAcceleration.z = userAccelerationLpf.z; 

NSLog(@"acc = %f, %f, %f", userAcceleration.x, userAcceleration.y, userAcceleration.z);
```

All I have here are zeros!!!!!!!!

The reading method repeats at 30 Hz.

this is taken from Apple sample and should not be giving me zeros!
any clues?

thanks.

Comment: Just to check, are you running this on the device and not the Simulator?

Comment: I have rotation data but not acceleration...

Comment: What do you see if you drop the low-pass filter and just log the raw acceleration?

Comment: @wetsider Well, if I drop the lines I the 4 lines before the NSLog, I see something that appears to be the data. So, why is that if this code is taken from a working sample from Apple?

Comment: @wetsider - solved the problem. I have commented out the line declaring userAccelerationLpf when I was testing and forgot to turn it on again. Thanks. Please add your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @DigitalRobot i also am working with this example, trying to get rotation details (when the device is rotated 90, 180, 360 or flipped).  just curious if you have anything u could point me to that might help me because when i output the rotation, and translation i dont get values i would expect.  theoretically, it should be like a graph resetting once it gets past 360

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you see if you drop the low-pass filter and just log the raw acceleration? (I bet I know the answer :)